# Load .png into xcode and convert to UIImage

Tags: xcode, uiimage, png, sparrow-framework

I'm completely new to Xcode, obj-c etc, but I want to use Parse.com to save an image to their server, they say you have to use this line, to convert a UIImage to NSData

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

How would I load one of the .png's that is in my resource folder and then convert it to a UIImage? I'm also using the Sparrow Framework if that helps any.

**EDIT**

I've tried this code as suggested below.

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terrainHexAtlas_v1@2x.png" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);

PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"terrainHexAtlas_v1@2x.png" data:imageData];
    [imageFile save];
```

But nothing seems to be happening. I tried a breakpoint at the last line and the vars imagePath, myImage, imageData are all 00000000 which I don't get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should follow code:

```
//png
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_image" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
NSData *pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);

//jpeg
NSString *imagePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_image" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *myImage2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath2];
NSData *jpegImageData = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage2, 1.0f)];
```

---

### Do not contain an extension in pathForResource. check following mistake case.

// not contain an extension

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_image.png" ofType:nil];
```

// contain an extension

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_image" ofType:@"png"];
```

// some people mistake case. wrong code. that return **`nil`**

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_image.png" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: How would I do the same for a .jpg? There doesn't seem to be a UIImageJPGRepresentation ?

Comment: you should following Method use: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(<#UIImage *image#>, <#CGFloat compressionQuality#>);

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested, but as I updated in my original question, nothing is happening, nothing is being saved to parse.

Comment: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terrainHexAtlas_v1@2x.png" ofType:@"png"]; is wrong. check out following code. pathForResource check please. Do not contain an extension in pathForResource. [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terrainHexAtlas_v1@2x" ofType:@"png"];